# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'predict' | Unable to do Prediction on Test Data in Heat Diseases Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, kaggle

I tried to predict on test data, but getting below error message, which something new to me. Everything going well, only the prediction part not being done.

> numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'predict'

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr_clf = LogisticRegression()
lr_clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
lr_clf.predict(x_test)
```

Kindly check my Kaggle Notebook, where I practiced, but not able to solve this problem after the struggle to check for the solution over the internet.

https://www.kaggle.com/rkraiscientist/heart-diseases-predictions-classifications-model

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. In below line you overwrite the LogisticRegression() class to a numpy array. And obviously numpy arrays how no predict() methods.

`lr_clf = lr_clf.score(x_test,y_test)*100`

Remove this line or assign it to another variable and run it again.

Comment: Thank you so much @enesdemirag, got your answer. A silly mistake from my side.